# not able to check AsyncTask result

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a problem that I am not able to check the value of AsyncTask result in order to start new activity if the result is desirable.

Here is my onPostExecute method:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
```

It toasts string value from php file and it has two possible values, "You are successfully logged in" or "Incorrect email or password". Everything is working fine until I want to check what the toasted message is, because if login is successfull I need to start a new activity.

This is how I tried to do that:

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AttemptLogin login = new AttemptLogin();
            try {
                String res = login.execute("http://10.0.2.2/loginApp.php").get();
                if (res.equals("You are successfully logged in"))
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ConnectActivity.class));                                                                               
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

I am totally confused because when I toast res, I get the desirable message, so the problem is with this line,**if (res.equals("You are successfully logged in"))**. The app behaves like this line doesn't exist at all.

I also tried with if(AsyncTask.getStatus() == FINISHED) and then to check AsyncTask result but it didn't help.

I really don't have idea what is going on, can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: never EVER! use `.get()` with an async task, that blocks the ui thread. If you want to get something from an async task use `onPostExecute` or create a callback that fires when your async task is finished

Comment: Move `if (res.equals("You are successfully logged in")) ` condition in `onPostExecute ` and also remove `get()` method. probably problem is occurring due to extra space in string so try it using `contains` instead of `equals`

Comment: Contains did the work and I removed condition in onPostExecute as you and Pier said. Thank you very much. I cannot believe that I spent so much time trying to fix this and I didn't come up with idea to use contains instead of equals. It's quite frustrating, but ok I am still farily new in adnroid programming, hopefully I will improve. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask has OnPostExecute and OnPreExecute methods.
Both of them can call items, variables and methods as if they were normal methods.

So in your onPostExecute you can easily check the result and start your activity using this:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute();
        try {

            if (s.equals("You are successfully logged in")){
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ConnectActivity.class);
                startActivity(i); 
            }                                                                              
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me, I moved condition into onPostExecute and with using contains instead of equals it is working fine